# What sort of applications we can develop for Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to start developing applications for Iphone but In confusion what are different types of apps I can develop Like **User level,Kernel Level,** or any other type. I want full detail about categories of  application development  for Iphone So I can choose one .

Comment: Gagan - welcome to SO!  We'd be happy to help with your question - could you please give more detail about what type of App you are thinking of creating?

Comment: I suggest looking into the ios sdk, that will give you an overview what you can do. You can't do anything besides what the sdk gives you without jailbreaking the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your apps to work, they must conform to the SDK/API at developer.apple.com. They are *user level* applications. You do not have access to the internals of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some ideas. You can head over the the App Store. There, you can browse all the categories and view products that people have created for the iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

First you start learning to create simple User Screens for iPhone app. Then think how much in you wanna go really...